# Взлом сайтов: литература

Tags: веб-программирование, взлом

Я в качестве хобби люблю взлом сайтов.
Подменить get/post, внедрить нулевой байт, найти и внедрить sql / xss инъекцию.
Люблю чужие косяки искать :)
Так вот, не подскажете ли книжек каких? А то что ни найду - взлом почты, брутфорсинг аккаунтов и так далее. Может есть что-то более узконаправленное, для меня? (:

**UPD:**
*Ещё раз публично извиняюсь за неправильное трактование термина "дефейс"...*

Comment: @NeoTvidoz, какая литература может быть по дефейсу?)) для самого дефейса максимум html+css нужен, ну мб олдовые навыки рисования буквами и прочее веселье) 

А по взлому - так любая литература по безопасности в web, все, что дает доступ к запиливанию произвольного текста в вывод)

Народ, дефейсинг - самое безобидное и при этом хакерское, не минусуйте) А то человек психанет и на бэкдоры переключится))

Comment: Не, так, сломал -> закрыл уязвимость -> пошел дальше :) А еще лучше на локалке у себя буйствовать, благо сейчас всяких движков предостаточно.

Comment: > Может есть что-то более узконаправленное, для меня?

Хм... тюремная камера, например?

Comment: Извиняюсь, имелось в виду - взлом, теперь прочитал что такое дефейс... ) Нет мне прощенья. Я в случае нахождения дыры сразу стучу девелоперам, никогда в корыстных целях и в целях "дефейса" ничего не ломал. Мне сам процесс нравится просто.

Comment: @NeoTvidoz

>Мне сам процесс нравится просто.

Мне тоже :)

Comment: Внезапно плюсую. Резко негативная рекация от тяп-ляп строителей, оставляющих дыры вполне понятна, но даже им прочтение обзорного текста об уязвимостях должно бы быть крайне полезно.

Comment: Колисниченоко "Профессиональное программирование на PHP". Там немного омвещены проблемы безопасности. Крупицы, но все же.

Comment: @Sh4dow, вы действительно считаете, что все пользователи минусуют вопрос потому, что сами не умеют грамотно писать код, а не, к примеру, потому что считают, что подобным бестолковым вопросам от малолетних школьников, начитавшихся хакера, не место на ХешКоде?

---

PS Забавно наблюдать стадный эффект. Стоит одному троллю, не различающему понятия реляционной модели БД, попытаться оскорбить других участников форума, как ему тут же начинают поддакивать и плюсовать вопрос, лишь бы их не уличили в говнокодерстве :)

Comment: "Я в качестве хобби люблю взлом сайтов." - ну у вас и хобби =0

Answer (score 7):

[Журнал **`Хакер`**](http://www.xakep.ru/articles/magazine/xa.asp) - там практически в каждом номере поднимается тема **`уязвимостей XML-RPC`**, **`XSS`**, **`SQL инъекций`**, и множество других подобных тем.

---

*Вот, например, [номер 160](http://www.xakep.ru/xa/?id=160) - там про ошибки в **`XML`** разметке приводящие к **нехорошим** последствиям XD.*

Comment: Я тоже читал ту статью в 160 номере =)

Comment: А про **`XSS`** на [demotivators.ru](http://demotivators.ru)?? XD 
Это вроде в прошлогоднем каком-то было...,
да, точно в [**`155`**](http://www.xakep.ru/xa/?id=155)

Comment: Битая ссылка, @niki-timofe....

Comment: @Asen,  спасиб, **`http://`** забыл XD

Comment: @niki-timofe, читал! Это по-моему мартовский или апрельский номер был =)

Comment: Декабрьский XD

Comment: Ну да, точно =)

Answer (score 4):

[Создание защищенных от вторжения прикладных программ](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/4260472/)

Книга в основном по защите, но есть много примеров уязвимостей, в том числе и создание инструмента для проверки уязвимости Web-приложения.

Answer (score 2):

Хех, я тоже как-то в свое время увлекался этим =) Изучал уязвимости, которые "предоставляет" использование XML. XML Injection - одна из самых баяновых уязвимостей, но тем не менее, с ее помощью был взломан Яндекс( на конкурсе, предоставляемом самим Яндексом ). Основное, что помогает "ломать" сайты бэкдором через XML - это XSL - группа языков, преобразующая XML-документы. Вот погуглите на эту тему. Тема интересная =)

Answer (score 1):

А причем тут хоббинехобби? Это называется поиск уязвимостей или проверка на безопасность и этим официально занимаются тест команды.

Скачай несколько таких прог для проверки и посмотри описания - там приводят уязвимости плюс вокруг них большие форумы там и пообщаешься с такими же любителями)

А книжки рекомендовать бесполезно - уязвимости быстро прикрываются и книги устаревают за неделю.